# Why doesn't use Indexes?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT id
FROM logo
WHERE (`description` LIKE "%google%" AND `active` = "y")
ORDER BY id ASC
```

the table `logo` (MyISAM) is formed by about 30 fields with 2402024 rows in it. 
the field `description` is a varchar(255) not null. 
the field `active` is an ENUM('y','n') not null 
the cardinality of those indexes are:

```
`active`: BTREE Card. 2 
`description`: BTREE Card. 200168
```

EXPLAIN on the query returns this:

```
select_type: SIMPLE 
table: logo 
type: ALL 
possible_keys: active 
key: NULL 
key_len: NULL 
ref: NULL 
rows: 2402024 
Extras: Using where
```

I am wondering why the query is not using the `description` index and how can I optimize the table so this query will run smoothly without a full table scan

Already optimized the table and checked for errors..

Comment: the sql engine can only use an index for 'starts-with' so 'google%' will use an index. Looking for a substring in a field forces the engine to a full table scan.

Comment: Anyway I can modify the table to speed up the query ? maybe partitioning ?

Comment: You're better off with a full-text-search thingy...http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your `LIKE` condition has a `%` at the beginning and end of the expression being compared, an index is useless in this context.

An index is only useful if the comparison expression can be found in an "ordered" fashion, as in A comes before B, which comes before C.  In other words, `LIKE 'google%'` may use an index, while `LIKE '%google%'` will not.